# Running Yarn in Managed Mode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, microsoft-distributed-file-system, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to run the simple-yarn-app at https://github.com/hortonworks/simple-yarn-app in the Managed Mode.

- I have copied the jar from local to hdfs like

  ```
  $ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal simple-yarn-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /simple-yarn-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  ```
- When I try to run it like

  ```
  hadoop jar simple-yarn-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.hortonworks.simpleyarnapp.Client /bin/date 2 /simple-yarn-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
  ```

  I get `FAILED` as the state. I looked for the log at `$HADOOP_HOME/logs`, but I do not find an associated log.
- Will there be a log present somewhere in the HDFS?

Below is the error I get:

> `[[2~14/07/10 12:23:32 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
>       14/07/10 12:23:32 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
>       Submitting application application_1405002979164_0004
>       14/07/10 12:23:32 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1405002979164_0004 to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
>       Application application_1405002979164_0004 finished with state FAILED at 1405013016326

I get the following Diagnostic Report,

> ----------------Failure Diagnostics----------------
>       Application application_1405062676632_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1405062676632_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000 due to: .
>   Failing this attempt..
>    Failing the application.

How should I debug or fix this?

Comment: I suggest that you add the logs of `hadoop-yarn/userlogs/application_1405062676632_0002` as well. You might find more helpful informations there. Unfortunately the information error are not very clear and there is an opened issue on [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-2242) upon it.

Comment: @eliasah I don't see any directory with the name hadoop-yarn. The only userlogs directory I have is at /home/prasanna/library/hadoop/hadoop-2.2.0/logs and I do not see any log with this application id.

Comment: Then try to configure your log file in conf/ folders and reproduce your error

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if anybody else is going through the same problem, when running in managed mode for this application, upload jar to hdfs and give hdfs path.

bin/hadoop jar simple-yarn-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.hortonworks.simpleyarnapp.Client /bin/date 2 hdfs://XXX/user/XYZ/apps/simple/simple-yarn-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar